# Is there a way to color code vscode status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode status bar has many sub-sections like, scope, line/col number, tab size, git branch.

Is there a way to color each sub-section differently so that i can easily focus on right info quickly?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color for all the things you can modify the color of the status bar, specifically https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#status-bar-colors.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to color each sub-section differently so that i can easily focus on right info quickly?

There will be an official and native way with VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)

> ### [Statusbar Entry background color API](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/7949224cbb52e868b9b2e121e01987bee533599f/release-notes/v1_52.md#status-bar-entry-background-color-apinotes/v1_52.md#statusbar-entry-background-color-api)
>
> We propose a new property `backgroundColor` for `StatusBarItem` to set the background color of a status bar entry.
>
> Currently only `statusBarItem.errorBackground` is supported to avoid that the status bar looks too colorful.
> We may expand this support to more colors in the future.
>
> [image: Status Error -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/status-error.png]
>
> The use case for this new API is to enable extensions to indicate error conditions in the Status bar.
> For example, the ESLint extension may decide to use this color to alert the user that ESLint has not yet been enabled for a workspace.

---

This is stabilized with VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021) with [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110214#issuecomment-736089306)

> I've updated the default color tokens to use a darker color of `errorForeground` since majority of themes have a much lighter color and to pass color contrast ratio in our dark/light themes:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/35271042/100672300-952d4080-3316-11eb-910d-7000856927ad.gif]

---

VSCode 1.59 (Jul. 2021) includes:

> ### [Status Bar Warning colors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/9f69164ec2c1d8c9009e092c4637dfb1f06310ae/release-notes/v1_59.md#status-bar-warning-colors)
>
> Status Bar Items that represent warnings can use the newly added `colors statusBarItem.warningBackground` and `statusBarItem.warningForeground`.

Comment: Is there a similar API to change the color of whole statusBar and not just StatusBarItem?

Comment: @vincentmathew The status bar itself would be part of the VSCode theme, as illustrated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62364107/6309. Not sure if an API is needed for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can install the [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) extension and create a css file which VS Code takes in. In that file you can set all the color rules you want for each status bar section.

[I've recorded a video on it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leVPkvQLALw&list=PLVwLx67OHLu0mEz51BK0B89MZ9HG-6hpi&index=10)

Comment: thanks for response, I use the extension, but maybe I am doing something wrong. I am using following in css to highlight a section in status bar:

.monaco-workbench .monaco-grid-view .monaco-grid-branch-node .monaco-split-view2 .split-view-container
.split-view-view .split-view-view .part.statusbar .right-items .amos402.scope-bar {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

also when I try to run the extension I get "Run VSCode in admin so that changes can be applied". I have made sure to change permission of VScode to myself.

Comment: Oh you just need to follow the instructions on the `Custom CSS and JS Loader` extension page to allow VS Code to modify itself and load the CSS file: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css