# Visual Studio Code status bar text color

Tags: visual-studio-code, background-color, statusbar

I want to change text color on status bar in Visual Studio Code. I've found how to change color of status bar [Visual Studio Code status bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780975/visual-studio-code-status-bar-color) but I need similar solution for text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two values you need to change for the status bar are

```
{
  "statusBar.background": "#114F79",
  "statusBar.foreground": "#9DE2FD"
}
```

And set those to your preference (in settings.json).

Comment: Thanks. "statusBar.foreground": "#000000" and "activityBar.foreground":  "#000000" works for me.