# How to prevent status bar colour in visual studio code from changing to orange on running any java file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have default blue colour status bar in visual studio code and I am fine with it.

[image]

see below:

When I am running any java file, status bar blinks and changes to orange intermittently before turing back blue again. This orange blinking is quite annoying.

I checked preferences: Settings(json) but don't see any option where its configured to change colour when running any java file: It looks below when java program running is in progress:

[image]

Comment: Please cover your private information in screenshot when you ask question here.

Comment: @MollyWang Noted and will follow going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you may run the file by Pressing `F5`, which is keyboard shortcuts for **Start Debugging**.

[image]

So different color in terminal bar is to distinguish **debug** from **run** these two status.

[image]

Click the triangle run button [image] or press `Ctrl+F5` to **Run without debugging** can both avoid the orange bar.

Comment: Answer was to the point. Screenshots let me follow it very easily.

Answer (score 3):

You can change colour of status bar in setting by adding colour customization as below in open settings file

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "statusBar.background" : "#1A1A1A",
    "statusBar.noFolderBackground" : "#212121",
    "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#263238"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for info but i was looking to avoid colour change which was happening because of debug getting enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent commit which addresses this:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/7f6a92727c3c40dc94ace4c0ee9265481c5424c5

It looks like the setting to disable the status bar changing color on debug will be:

```
debug.enableStatusBarColor
```

The default is `true` so you will have to set it to `false` to disable it.